# Microsoft Edge does not render the style well

Tags: css

I have an oval with css, in Chrome render well, but in Microsoft Edge doesn't. Here are my pics about that:

**EDGE**

[image]

**CHROME or Firefox**

[image]

This is my class:

```css
.ovalo {
  margin-left: -3.2rem;
  top: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #343434;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  border-width: thin 10px;
  transition: all;
  border-radius: 150px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10 50% / 0 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 50% / 0 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80%;
  border: 4px solid #343434;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<div class="ovalo"></div>
```

Comment: because you have set a weird webkit border radius - remove it (or set it to 150px) and the border radius will be the same as chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
border-radius: 150px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10 50% / 0 100%;
-moz-border-radius: 0 50% / 0 100%;
```

This code is culprit for that display. This should be same to render properly across all browser. In-fact you can trim all those browser prefix just put `border-radius: valu` will be ok on over 98% browsers on Earth! [Here is proof.](https://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius)